# Excluding weekend and holidays from my days number

Tags: formula-field, date

I want to retreive the weekend and holidays from my days number! I've created a formula field named weekend where I put :

```
CASE(MOD( Start_date__c - DATE(1985,6,24),7),
0 , CASE( MOD( End_date__c - Start_date__c, 7),1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,1,6,2,0),
1 , CASE( MOD( End_date__c - Start_date__c, 7),0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,2,2),
2 , CASE( MOD( End_date__c - Start_date__c, 7),0,0,1,0,2,0,3,1,2),
3 , CASE( MOD( End_date__c - Start_date__c, 7),0,0,1,0,2,1,2),
4 , CASE( MOD( End_date__c - Start_date__c, 7),0,0,1,1,2),
5 , CASE( MOD( End_date__c - Start_date__c, 7),0,1,2),
6 , CASE( MOD( End_date__c - Start_date__c, 7),6,2,1),
999)
+
(FLOOR(( End_date__c - Start_date__c )/7)*2)
```

In the other hand I have days number defining this way:

```
(IF(TEXT(Start_date__c)= TEXT(End_date__c) , 0.0, End_date__c - Start_date__c)) - Weekend__c
```

I want to combine them!

Comment: Your question title mentions holidays but your formula does not make any reference to them. Please confirm that it is just week days and weekends you are dealing with and not holidays.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Business Hours object in the salesforce to attain this functionality.

[Salesforce Documentation Link for Business Hours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm)

Here is one example for using it -

```
    Date txnDate = System.today();
    Date systemDate = txnDate.addDays(10);

    Integer holidaysCount = 0;
    BusinessHours bh;
    List<BusinessHours> temp = [SELECT ID, Name, IsDefault, IsActive From BusinessHours 
                                    WHERE IsDefault = true 
                                    OR Name = 'BANK'];
    for (BusinessHours b : temp) {
        if (b.IsDefault) {
            bh = b;
        }
    }
    while (txnDate != systemDate) {
        Datetime now = Datetime.newInstance(txnDate.year(), txnDate.month(), txnDate.day(), 0, 0, 0);        
        Boolean isHoliday = !BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.Id, now);
        System.debug('The value of isHoliday is : '+isHoliday);
        if (isHoliday) {
            holidaysCount++;
        }
        txnDate = txnDate.addDays(1);
    }
    System.debug('The holidays are : '+holidaysCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

As:

```
weekdays + weekenddays = calendardays
```

I am unclear what your problem is: given two of these you can always have a formula to get the third.

You've probably seen this already but here is a standard reference for [Formula - Weekend Days or Workdays Calculation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004526).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method to not allow Task due date to not fall on the weekends, it may point you in the right direction..

```
public static Date changeWeekendTaskDueDate(Date thedate)
{
    Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(thedate, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
    String dayOfWeek=dt.format('E');
    Integer offset = 0;

    if(dayOfWeek == 'Sat')
    {
        offset = 2;
    }
    else if(dayOfWeek == 'Sun')
    {
        offset = 1;
    }

    return thedate + offset;
}
```